# Как вывести на печать к примеру третий и второй элемент из связного списка

Tags: python, списки, linked-list

На печать выводится только первый и последний, а как быть с теми которые между них?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value = None, next = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.length = 0

    def add(self, enter):
        if self.first == None:
            self.last = Node(enter, None)
            self.first = Node(enter,enter)
        else:
            self.last = Node(self.last.value, None)
            new = self.first
            self.first = Node(value= enter, next = new)



a = LinkedList()
a.add(1)
a.add(2)
a.add(3)
a.add(4)
print(a.first.value)
print(a.first.next)
print(a.last.value)
print(a.last.next)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я поправил логику добавления элементов, добавил метод добавления элемента в начало. Для поэлементного обхода добавил метод `__iter__`, который последовательно возвращает узлы списка. Метод для обращения по индексу не добавлял, т.к. это не очень соответствует логике обработки связных списков.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value = None, next = None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next
    
    def __repr__(self):
        # Нужно для отображения объекта в виде Node(value=1)
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(value={self.value!r})"


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.length = 0

    def append(self, value):
        """
        Метод добавления элемента в конец
        """
        new_node = Node(value, None)
        if self.first == None:
            # Если список пустой
            # то созданный узел одновременно будет первым и последним
            self.last = new_node
            self.first = new_node
        else:
            # Если список не пустой
            self.last.next = new_node  # Делаем созданный узел следующим для последнего
            self.last = new_node  # Перенаправляем ссылку последнего узла на только что созданный
        
        self.length += 1
    
    def prepend(self, value):
        """
        Метод добавления элемента в начало
        """
        self.first = Node(value, self.first)
        if self.last == None:
            self.last = self.first
        
        self.length += 1
    
    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Итерация по элементам списка
        """
        if self.first:
            current = self.first
            while current:
                yield current
                current = current.next


a = LinkedList()
a.append(1)
a.append(2)
a.append(3)
a.append(4)

# Вывод с проходом по списку через for
for item in a:
    print(item, item.value)

# Итерируемые объекты можно преобразовывать в другие типы итерируемых объектов, например в список:
print(list(a))  # [Node(value=1), Node(value=2), Node(value=3), Node(value=4)]

# Чтобы вывести второй элемент, нужно вызвать итератор списка два раза:
it = iter(a)
next(it)  # Первый элемент пропускаем
print(next(it))  # Выводим второй
print(next(it))  # Выводим третий
```

Вывод:

```
Node(value=1) 1
Node(value=2) 2
Node(value=3) 3
Node(value=4) 4
[Node(value=1), Node(value=2), Node(value=3), Node(value=4)]
Node(value=2)
Node(value=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, ptr_next):
        self.value = value
        self.ptr_next = ptr_next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ptr_end = None

    def append(self, value):
        elem = Node(value, None)
        try:
            self.head
        except AttributeError:
            self.head = elem
            self.ptr_end = elem
        else:
            self.ptr_end.ptr_next = elem
            self.ptr_end = elem
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        for _idx, value in enumerate(self):
            if _idx == idx:
                return value
        raise IndexError('This index not found: %s' % idx)

    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            elem = self.head
        except AttributeError:
            raise StopIteration('List is empty')
        else:
            while True:
                yield elem.value
                elem = elem.ptr_next
                if elem is None:
                    break
            raise StopIteration('End')
        pass


a = LinkedList()
a.append(1)
a.append(2)
a.append(3)
a.append(4)
print(a[0])
print(a[3])
print(list(a))
```

доступ по индексам типа a[-1] может быть только в двухнаправленном списке, у вас же он однонаправленый..)

Comment: Нет нужды явно выбрасывать StopIteration. `a[-1] == a[len(a)-1]` для стандартных последовательностей в Питоне.